# Scalable Text generated by Java 2D?

Tags: java, excel, java-2d

Is there a drawString method usable in java that will create scalable text that will be clear and crisp in a powerpoint presentation?

Backstory:

---

I screwed up. Big time.

A friend of mine asked for help with automating some graph creation for his company. The process involved taking in data values from a pdf file, then converting them into graphs to be exported into an image file that he could then use to place in a power point. I figured it would be easy enough to do in Java2D, and therefore used the Graphics library to do so.

The resulting image looks good, except that there is small text written by him through his manual process (which is done in excel), that I cannot replicate with my automated program. It seems that because he has created his image using excel this small text will scale well when blown up for a power point presentation, whereas when I use Java2D's drawText method it will look pixelated and blocky as this seems to draw it pixel by pixel.

I realize now that this would have been much better done using Visual Basic or through Excel macro's that are made with this sort of thing, however at this point I do not have the time to begin anew. :(

Comment: So, you have a string in code of the text you want to render right?  And you are rendering this text to your image?  Have you enabled anti-aliasing for text?

Comment: I have been using Java2D's drawString() method to write the text onto the picture, I don't know if it's even possible to enable anti-aliasing for the text

Comment: [Here's a guide.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/renderinghints.html)